# Laravel - How to use the Advanced Routing properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a book list which are in categories and subcategories.

Every category hasMany Subcategories. And every subcategory belongsTo a category in my Models.

Now I want to have **routes** like this:

books/{category?}

and

books/{category?}/{subcategory?}

my **Routes** look like this:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'ReligionsController');

Route::resource('category/{category?}', 'ReligionBranchController');

Route::get('category/{category?}/{subcategory?}', function()
{
    return 'Quitter never win';
});
```

Now the Problem is, that my 2nd route works perfectly find, with my ReligionBranchController, but my last route (3rd) isn't working at all and I get this message:

```
 Route pattern "/categories/{category}/{{category}}" cannot reference variable name "category" more than once.
```

How am I going to use dynamic routes like this:

```
 example.org/category/fear/thriller
 example.org/category/love/drama
 example.org/category/love/science-fiction
```

Hope someone understands my trouble.

Comment: The error you are showing us is for the first route `Route pattern "/categories/` and not the third, which starts with `category` and not `categories`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must undestand that Laravel tries to resolve routes the faster it can, so your most generic routes must be the last ones, that being said, I recommend you to change the order of your routes to:

```
Route::get('category/{category}/{subcategory}', function()
{
    return 'Quitter never win';
});

Route::resource('category/{category?}', 'ReligionBranchController');

Route::resource('categories', 'ReligionsController');
```

Also, this route

```
Route::get('category/{category?}/{subcategory?}', function() ...
```

Is exactly the same as

```
Route::get('category/{category?}', function()
```

If your user pass only one parameter, or no parameters at all, so I also recommend to change it to:

```
Route::get('category/{category}/{subcategory}', function() ...
```

This way, if someone gives category AND subcategory it will enter the first one, if just category OR no category, the second one.